# operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. source microsoft.azure.amqp in eventhub using dotnet core 5

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub, asp.net-core-5.0

I updated my framework from dotnet core 3.1 to 5.0 stable but **facing below issue while calling CreateBatchAsync() of eventhub producer using producer client**.
I have an application which post events to azure eventhub. It is kind of event producer.
Previously it has been working fine with older version of dotnet core 3.1 but after the release of dotnet 5. It is throwing below error:

```
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.Flush()
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<FlushAsync>b__39_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ForceAuthenticationAsync>d__171`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToApm.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransport.HandleOpenComplete(IAsyncResult result, Boolean syncComplete)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.HandleTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.OnTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.<CreateAndOpenConnectionAsync>d__60.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.<OpenProducerLinkAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.<CreateLinkAndEnsureProducerStateAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.<CreateLinkAndEnsureProducerStateAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.<CreateBatchAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpProducer.<CreateBatchAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient.<CreateBatchAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient.<CreateBatchAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at \EventHubSender\EventSendService.cs:line 42
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known net core 5.0 issue: [ampq 165](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp/issues/165).

Seems like it was fixed though. I checked the code in [2.4.8](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp/releases/tag/v2.4.8) release, and it seems that the problematic line of code was removed.

Try updateing the `azure-amqp` library to the `2.4.8` version and see if it works.

[This link mentions the following](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13899):

> 1. Workaround: TransportType=AmqpWebSockets
> 2. Installing version 2.4.6 of Microsoft.Azure.Amqp fixed the issue on my side

Comment: The `v5.3.0-beta` releases of the Event Hubs client library reference the fixed version of the AMQP library, if you're in a non-production setting where prereleases is an option.   As was mentioned, the `AmqpWebSockets` protocol is the recommended workaround for v5.2.0 and lower of the client library.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification! I mentioned both for completeness!

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras Its working with 2.4.8. previously it was part of eventhub meta package in which it is 2.4.5. But After manually installing its latest package it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I had the same problem. Just updated the "Microsoft.Azure.Amqp" package to version 2.4.13 and the error was removed

Comment: In what way does your answer contribute to the post and specifically to the already given answer?